# Is there a similar way to push navigation in Angular 6 like we do in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to navigate to a different page in Angular 6.

In Ionic we do it by calling `navCtrl.push('ExamplePage')`;

In Angular 6 I understand they are routes but I'm not being able to navigate using a button like:

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)='goToExamplePage()'>ExamplePage</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
constructor(private router: Router)

goToExamplePage(){
    this.router.navigate(['/example'])
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

 const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: AppComponent},
  { path: 'example',     component: ExampleComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ExampleComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      { enableTracing: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
    )
   ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
```

It simply doesn't do anything. Any help please?

Comment: Any errors in the console when you click the button?

Comment: no errors. tried catching but returns null

Comment: Try `this.router.navigate(['example'])` without the forward slash.

Comment: I have tried this already but it duplicates the button on the home page and when clicking it shows the ExampleComponent on the home page. That's not what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to navigate to other page, not implementing it into the view.

Answer (score 0):

For those still arriving here with questions. This is the correct way of manually navigating to a route.

The problem above is that `AppComponent` is the `bootstrap` component as well as the root route (`'/'`) component. The reasons you are not seeing an endless nested template is because Angular only uses the outer `<router-outlet/>`.

Here is a basic manual navigation example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pykkry. Edit the app and add the app component as the root route as see the effect.